# pgfplots - how to create a horizontal line plot in a bar chart with symbolic x axis labels

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I was wondering if there was a way to get the line plots "Unseamed" and "Requirement" to span the whole width of the graph not just from the centre points of the first and last x axis labels. Is there a way to create invisible x axis labels to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=11cm,
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.3,legend style={at={(0.98,0.98)},
cells={anchor=west}
},
legend entries={Straight,Unseamed,Zigzag,Requirement},
bar width=1cm,legend columns=2,
ylabel={Tensile strength{,} $N\,mm^{-1}$},
symbolic x coords={Plain,Single lap,Double lap},
xtick=data,
ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\addplot [draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,7)+-(0.41,0.41)
(Single lap,11)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,12)+-(0.47,0.47)
};

\addplot[black,sharp plot]
coordinates {(Plain,10.857) (Double lap,10.857)}
;

\addplot [draw=black,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,4)+-(0.31,0.31)
(Single lap,5)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,6)+-(0.38,0.38)
};

\addplot[black,sharp plot,dashed]
coordinates {(Plain,3.430) (Double lap,3.430)}
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Is it `3.430` for both of them ? I mean both of them are horizontal lines?

Comment: Percusse - I would like the two horizontal line plots to span the whole width of the graph (i.e. touching the y axis).

Answer (score 11):

Here is a somewhat roundabout way of achieving this. First add `\coordinate`s at `(Plain,3.43)` and `(Plain, 10.857)`, and in the lower corners with the `rel axis cs` coordinate system, then draw lines using these coordinate as reference. Legend entries are added with `\addlegendimage`.

Note that units should not generally be written in italics, so a change there is recommended. You could do `$\mathrm{N}\,\mathrm{mm}^{-1}$`, but a better way of handling units is the `siunitx` package, which lets you write `\si{\newton\per\square\milli\metre}`. In addition, I can mention the `units` library of `pgfplots`, the features of which can be combined with `siunitx` as in the code below (taken from the `pgfplots` manual).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{unit code/.code 2 args={\si{#1#2}}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=11cm,
ybar,
y unit=\newton\per\square\milli\metre,
enlargelimits=0.3,
legend style={
at={(0.98,0.98)},
cells={anchor=west},
column 3/.style={width=2cm}
},
legend entries={Straight,Unseamed,Zigzag,Requirement},
bar width=1cm,legend columns=2,
ylabel={Tensile strength},
symbolic x coords={Plain,Single lap,Double lap},
xtick=data,
ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\addplot [draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,7)+-(0.41,0.41)
(Single lap,11)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,12)+-(0.47,0.47)
};

\addlegendimage{line legend,black,sharp plot}

\addplot [draw=black,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,4)+-(0.31,0.31)
(Single lap,5)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,6)+-(0.38,0.38)
};

\addlegendimage{line legend,black,sharp plot,dashed}


\coordinate (A) at (axis cs:Plain,3.430);
\coordinate (B) at (axis cs:Plain,10.857);
\coordinate (O1) at (rel axis cs:0,0);
\coordinate (O2) at (rel axis cs:1,0);

\draw [black,sharp plot,dashed] (A -| O1) -- (A -| O2);
\draw [black,sharp plot] (B -| O1) -- (B -| O2);


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```