# Dashed and Horizontal line in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Wants to draw a dashed and horizontal line starts from y=98.23 (pointed in the attached image with an arrow)in a tikzpicture bar graph. [image]

Following is the code

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns}

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{justification = centering}
    \subfloat[xxx]{ 
        \label{11(a)}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =.5, transform shape]
        \begin{axis}[   
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar = 2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=7pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel={xxx(\%)},
        symbolic x coords={xx, yy, zz, ll},
        xtick=data, 
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=95,
        minor y tick num=5, 
        xlabel style={yshift=-.3cm},
        ylabel style={yshift=-.3cm},    
        tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
        legend style={at={(.5,-0.1)}, anchor=north, /tikz/every even 
column/.append style={column sep=.5cm}},
        legend columns = -1,
        ]
        \addplot[style = {fill=red, mark=none, postaction={pattern=dots}}, 
error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, error bar style ={thick}]   
        coordinates {
            (xx, 97.772418) +- (0.00477703, 0.00477703)  
            (yy, 96.83437) +- (0.039005931, 0.039005931) 
            (zz, 96.9428) +- (0.05470002, 0.05470002) 
            (ll, 96.72381) +- (0.023826187, 0.023826187)};
        \addplot[style = {fill=blue, mark=none, postaction={pattern=north 
east lines}}, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, error bar style = 
{thick}]
        coordinates {
            (xx, 97.615588) +- (0.036178026, 0.036178026)  
            (yy, 96.77373) +- (0.045379505, 0.045379505) 
            (zz, 97.61842) +- (0.036159489, 0.036159489) 
            (ll, 96.64351) +- (0.044978336, 0.044978336)};
        \addplot[style = {fill=green, mark=none, postaction= 
 {pattern=horizontal lines}}, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, error 
 bar style ={thick}]
        coordinates {
            (xx, 98.856128) +- (0.031866164, 0.031866164)  
            (yy, 99.00258) +- (0.026840445, 0.026840445) 
            (zz, 98.02313) +- (0.057913644, 0.057913644) 
            (ll, 98.30856) +- (0.048969882, 0.048969882)};
        \addplot[style = {fill=yellow, mark=none, postaction= 
{pattern=vertical lines}}, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, error bar 
 style ={thick}]
        coordinates {
            (xx, 97.778428) +- (0.035212399, 0.035212399)  
            (yy, 96.82722) +- (0.045398952, 0.045398952) 
            (zz, 97.75243) +- (0.034266698, 0.034266698) 
            (ll, 96.72982) +- (0.043016218, 0.043016218)};  
        \legend{xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106540/pgfplots-how-to-create-a-horizontal-line-plot-in-a-bar-chart-with-symbolic-x-a/163145#163145 helps

Comment: Did either Torbjørn T.'s link or my answer answer your question or do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the given solution by Torbjørn T. in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434118/dashed-and-horizontal-line-in-tikzpicture#comment1088164_434118) you could also add an `extra y tick` to achieve the desired result. The only tricky part is to move this line before the bars (when the "normal" grid lines should still be behind the bars).

(I also "optimized" your code a bit which now should be simpler and hopefully more readable.)

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    % use this `compat' level or higher to make use of the advanced label positioning
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale =.5,
    transform shape,
]
    \begin{axis}[
        ymin=95,
        ylabel={xxx (\%)},
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=7pt,
        % ----------
        % (adapted. This looks a bit strange, but currently has to be done
        %  in this way because of <https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/182/>.)
        major tick length=0pt,
        ytick style={
            /pgfplots/major tick length=1.5mm,
        },
        % ----------
        ymajorgrids=true,
        symbolic x coords={xx, yy, zz, ll},
        xtick=data,
        % align the xtick labels at the baseline
        typeset ticklabels with strut,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        minor y tick num=5,
        legend columns = -1,
        legend style={
            at={(xticklabel cs:.5)},            % <-- (adapted)
            anchor=north,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={
                column sep=.5cm,
            },
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % added stuff
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % allow different layers
        set layers,
        % (needed because of bug <https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/153/>)
        cell picture=true,
        % now add the "horizontal line" ...
        extra y ticks=98.23,
        % ... don't show any label and ...
        extra y tick labels={},
        % ... adapt the style to your needs
        extra y tick style={
            % in case you should remove the grid from the "normal" ticks ...
            ymajorgrids=true,
            % ... but don't show an extra tick (line)
            ytick style={
                /pgfplots/major tick length=0pt,
            },
            grid style={
                red,
                dashed,
                % to draw this line before the bars, move it a higher layer
                /pgfplots/on layer=axis foreground,
            },
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % moved common options from the `\addplot' commands here
        mark=none,
        error bars/y dir=both,
        error bars/y explicit,
        error bars/error bar style={
            thick,
        },
    ]

        \addplot [
            fill=red,
            postaction={pattern=dots},
        ] coordinates {
            (xx, 97.772418) +- (0.00477703, 0.00477703)
            (yy, 96.83437)  +- (0.039005931, 0.039005931)
            (zz, 96.9428)   +- (0.05470002, 0.05470002)
            (ll, 96.72381)  +- (0.023826187, 0.023826187)
        };

        \addplot [
            fill=blue,
            postaction={pattern=north east lines},
        ] coordinates {
            (xx, 97.615588) +- (0.036178026, 0.036178026)
            (yy, 96.77373)  +- (0.045379505, 0.045379505)
            (zz, 97.61842)  +- (0.036159489, 0.036159489)
            (ll, 96.64351)  +- (0.044978336, 0.044978336)
        };

        \addplot [
            fill=green,
            postaction={pattern=horizontal lines},
        ] coordinates {
            (xx, 98.856128) +- (0.031866164, 0.031866164)
            (yy, 99.00258)  +- (0.026840445, 0.026840445)
            (zz, 98.02313)  +- (0.057913644, 0.057913644)
            (ll, 98.30856)  +- (0.048969882, 0.048969882)
        };

        \addplot [
            fill=yellow,
            postaction={pattern=vertical lines},
        ] coordinates {
            (xx, 97.778428) +- (0.035212399, 0.035212399)
            (yy, 96.82722)  +- (0.045398952, 0.045398952)
            (zz, 97.75243)  +- (0.034266698, 0.034266698)
            (ll, 96.72982)  +- (0.043016218, 0.043016218)
        };

        \legend{xxx, xxx, xxx, xxx}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]