# How to draw a horizontal line in a stacked bar chart with symbolic x axis labels?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

According to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106540/pgfplots-how-to-create-a-horizontal-line-plot-in-a-bar-chart-with-symbolic-x-a), which perfectly works fine for a bar chart, I want to draw a horizontal line in a stacked bar chart. So, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=11cm,
ybar stacked,
enlargelimits=0.3,legend style={at={(0.98,0.98)},
cells={anchor=west}
},
legend entries={Straight,Unseamed,Zigzag,Requirement},
bar width=1cm,legend columns=2,
ylabel={Tensile strength{,} $N\,mm^{-1}$},
symbolic x coords={Plain,Single lap,Double lap},
xtick=data,
ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\addplot [draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,7)+-(0.41,0.41)
(Single lap,11)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,12)+-(0.47,0.47)
};

\addplot [draw=black,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,4)+-(0.31,0.31)
(Single lap,5)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,6)+-(0.38,0.38)
};

\addplot[black,sharp plot]
coordinates {(Plain,10.857) (Double lap,10.857)}
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image]

But what I need is a straight horizontal line which starts from the beginning of the x-axis to the end:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! Use `ybar stacked` only for those plots that really need it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=11cm,
enlargelimits=0.3,legend style={at={(0.98,0.98)},
cells={anchor=west}
},
legend entries={Straight,Unseamed,Zigzag,Requirement},
bar width=1cm,legend columns=2,
ylabel={Tensile strength{,} \si{\newton\per\milli\meter}},
symbolic x coords={Plain,Single lap,Double lap},
xtick=data,
ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\addplot [ybar stacked,draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,7)+-(0.41,0.41)
(Single lap,11)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,12)+-(0.47,0.47)
};

\addplot [ybar stacked,draw=black,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,4)+-(0.31,0.31)
(Single lap,5)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,6)+-(0.38,0.38)
};

\addplot[black,sharp plot]
coordinates {(Plain,10.857) (Double lap,10.857)}
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Off-topic: one usually typesets units upright, and the `siunitx` package can be used to do so.

To draw a line across the axis, you do not need a plot, but just a `\draw` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=11cm,
enlargelimits=0.3,legend style={at={(0.98,0.98)},
cells={anchor=west}
},
legend entries={Straight,Unseamed,Zigzag,Requirement},
bar width=1cm,legend columns=2,
ylabel={Tensile strength{,} \si{\newton\per\milli\meter}},
symbolic x coords={Plain,Single lap,Double lap},
xtick=data,
ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\addplot [ybar stacked,draw=black,pattern=crosshatch dots,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,7)+-(0.41,0.41)
(Single lap,11)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,12)+-(0.47,0.47)
};

\addplot [ybar stacked,draw=black,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,error bar style={line width=1pt}] 
coordinates
{
(Plain,4)+-(0.31,0.31)
(Single lap,5)+-(0.27,0.27)
(Double lap,6)+-(0.38,0.38)
};

\path (axis cs:{[normalized]1},10.857) coordinate (aux);

\end{axis}
\draw (current axis.west|-aux) -- (current axis.east|-aux);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the line does not start from the beginning to the end of the x-axis.

Comment: @Patris I added a version that does that.